# Can't attach listener to close dialog button

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces dialog framework. The dialog window have small x in the corner which closes it. Can I attach some code to it?

I've tried:

```
<p:commandButton id="btn_open" value="add" process="" update="messages" action="#{bean.openDialog}">
                <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{bean.onDialogClose}" update="messages"/>
            </p:commandButton>

public void onDialogClose(CloseEvent event){
}
```

but no avail, I never get to onDialogClose function.

I think it's wrong event or signature, but I can't find the answer in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dialogReturn` event must be handled by

```
public void onDialogReturn(SelectEvent event)
{
     Object obj = event.getObject();
}
```

which is explicitly fired by

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().close(obj);
```

on the dialog side.

Closing the dialog with the upper-right "X" button does not fire the `dialogReturn` event.

I don't know if it is possible at all to handle a dialog framework close event, the first thing that comes into my mind is to open the dialog with option `closable="false"` and create another button for closing it.

```
public void open(String outcome)
{
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("closable", false);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(outcome, options, null);
}
```

and then manage this state:

```
public void onDialogReturn(SelectEvent event)
{
     Object obj = event.getObject();
     if(obj == null)
     {
         // handle close
     }
     else
     {
         // handle object returned
     }
}
```

Comment: I used public void onDialogReturn() without a parameter, and closed the dialog with RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null); I think it's functionally same?

Comment: If you don't need to return an object from the dialog, then yes, it's the same.